# By VTM 5e, are the Kindred in the VtMB2 clan reveal trailers breaking any Camarilla laws?

Tags: world-of-darkness, lore, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

For reference: As of this question being posted, the current released *Vampire: the Masquerade - Bloodlines 2* clans are - Brujah, Tremere and Toreador (not counting Thin-blood).

This is prompted by how I saw a theory in the comments of one of the reveal videos, speculating whether the Kindred who appear in these videos might actually be the intended blood-hunt targets for the thin-blood PC.

They cited the following things as why they thought so:

- Brujah - Very *unsubtle* looking cases of arson and murder which
  could attract some undesired attention
- Tremere - Very *messy* blood ritual
- Toreador - Filming herself eating/murdering someone

Whether or not the theory is correct (that *not* being the topic/question here - just context), the Toreador at least, I do agree is likely doing something they *shouldn't* with making what is essentially a snuff video.

I'm not too sure of the severity of that by itself though, if she's not actually distributing it (I don't know), or about the others as they seem more of-norm.

Keeping in mind that the game does actually draw heavily and specifically from VTM 5E (even mentioning the fall of the Pyramid):

**By the rules set in the VTM 5e RPG, are any of the kindred in the VtMB2 clan reveal trailers actually committing any violations/breaking any laws of the Camarilla during them?**

Comment: Could the vampires be Sabbat? Or Anarchs?

Comment: I think you should update your comment since other clan have been revealed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is difficult to answer as it depends on the setting and circumstances that we are unaware of. I'm going to try anyway, while limiting it to members of the Camarilla breaching the Masquerade.

### The Brujah

Best case, this one is apparently in breach of the Masquerade. Even if the vampire didn't explicitly demonstrate superhuman powers it is still a mass murder in a public place. Witnesses describing this as the act of a single person will most likely draw attention from both media and law enforcement which could lead to problems further down the line. Just imagine the brujah being randomly spotted going into a vampire safe haven and a SWAT team busting down the door 30  minutes later.

### The Tremere

Very messy blood ritual, but it appears to be in a controlled environment with plenty of loyal slaves to clean up afterwards. This happening in a laboratory it may also be possible to make up an excuse if anyone find some overlooked spots of blood. As long as they can get rid of the evidence before the day shift starts I don't see a definite breach here.

### The Toreador

This one also depends on circumstances. We don't know how the videos are stored or the risk of them getting into the wrong hands. Best case this is an artist trying to stay sane and the videos will never see the light of day. Not a breach in itself, but probably a bad idea. (As a GM I like it when PCs do this as it lines up some nice personal plot hooks and possibilities for role play.)